# Field Extensions - Algebraic Extensions

Tags: extension-field

I have a question, How can I prove that $[\mathbb{Q}({\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{10}}):\mathbb{Q}]= 4$?.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you write elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{10})$?

Comment: It would help to know where you have gotten with this problem.  For example what is the dimension of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: I recommend that you read [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). Questions that look like copy/pasted assignments are magnets of negative attention.

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that $\mathbb{Q}({\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{10}})=\mathbb{Q}({\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5}})$ as $\sqrt {10}$ is in that field.
Second, it is possible (for example with Eisenstein's criterion) to show that $x^2-2$ and $x^2-5$ are irreducible.
The only thing that's left then would be showing that they cannot be acquired from each other which is a result of the fact they are relatively prime, and you can show this by showing that the set $\{1,\sqrt 2,\sqrt 5,\sqrt {10}\}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$ (which is almost directly from the fact that the two prime roots are irrational).

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{10}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5})$

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{10} = \sqrt{2} \sqrt{5}$, so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{10}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5})$.  $\sqrt{2} \not\in \mathbb{Q}$, and $(\sqrt{2})^2 - 2 = 0$, so $\mathrm{deg}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\sqrt{2}) = 2 = |\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) : \mathbb{Q}|$.  $\sqrt{5} \not\in \mathbb{Q}$, and $(\sqrt{5})^2 - 5 = 0$, so $\mathrm{deg}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\sqrt{5}) = 2 = |\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}) : \mathbb{Q}|$.  Therefore, $|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5}) : \mathbb{Q}| \in \{2,4\}$.  Perhaps you know $\sqrt{5} \not \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.  Otherwise, suppose $\sqrt{5} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, then${}^{*}$ $\exists b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that either $b \sqrt{2} = c \sqrt{5}$, so $\sqrt{5/2} \in \mathbb{Q}$, a contradiction, or $1 + b \sqrt{2} = c \sqrt{5}$, $1 + 2 \sqrt{2} b + 2 b^2 = 5 c^2$, so $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$, also a contradiction.

${}^{*}$:  $a + b \sqrt{2} = c \sqrt{5}$.  If $a = 0$, $\frac{b}{c} = \sqrt{5/2}$.  Alternatively, $a \neq 0$, so $1 + \frac{b}{a} \sqrt{2} = \frac{c}{a} \sqrt{5}$.